# Is there any complication of using IFrames in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, devise, sendfile

I am trying to preview a PDF in my rails application. The file sits in the uploads folder and not in the public or assets folder. So I have a action in my controller called preview which uses send_file.

I have a before filter for preview called check_shared which checks if the user is allowed to view the file or not.

When this entire workflow works for a simple image preview where I just use an image_tag to render the image, it fails to work with an IFrame. An error arises in the check_shared private action which says that "current_user"( I am using Devise) is not a valid method.

Does the controller action somehow lose it's scope in the Iframe?

Here is the view:

```
<%= image_tag preview_myfile_path(@myfile) %>

<iframe src="/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=<%= preview_myfile_path(@myfile) %>" id="pdf_frame" style="border: 0" width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Here is the preview action:

```
def preview
    # Introducing choosepath, to reduce double render errors.
    send_file choosepath(@myfile)
end
```

Here is the before action:

```
def check_shared
      puts "inside check_shared"
      @myfile = Myfile.find(params[:id])
      if current_user.id == @myfile.user_id
        puts "owner!"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "You do not have permission to access this file!"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
```

Comment: Rails 4 enabling additional security protocols by default which prevent the iFrame to load. Are you facing problem loading iFrame?

Comment: No the iFrame is loading. But the preview's send_file is not loading since it fails at the before_action.